# Get position of specific point in a background-image

Tags: jquery, html, background-image

I'm building a responsive website with some background images that use `background-size: cover` to.. well... cover the a div with a background image. I need to always get the position for a specific part of the image, relative to the image, not its div.

For demonstration purposes only, consider the following scenario:

I use this image to cover a div
[image]

Now i want to always get the spot above the iPhone, despite the changing position of the image relative to its `div` caused by `background-size: cover`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want to use this to overlay `div`'s as labels or buttons over an image.
The obvious problem is, that my overlays are positioned relative to the parent div. But i need them to be relative to the iPhone in the image.

Here a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3NuDy/ Resize the frame!
The red label should always be directly above the iPhone.

Is this possible with HTML5, CSS3 **and Javascript (jQuery)** ?

Edit: added another image to illustrate the different positions of the iPhone (or red spot) relative to the div.

Edit2: added JSFiddle to illustrate my problem. Resize the frame! The red label should always be directly above the iPhone http://jsfiddle.net/3NuDy/

Comment: So work out the point in the image, then subtract any image location offsets

Comment: I've done something similiar, also with `background-size: cover;`. Its simply rule of three math. You have to read the `.offset();` of the overlays at a specific scale and use that factor to recalculate the new offset when resizing the browser window.

Comment: but how do i get the offsets between the edges of a background image and its div?

Comment: the iPhone won't do it??

Comment: @supersize: are you sure this would work? I mean, a background image could have `background-position: center top` or `left bottom` in addition to `background-size: cover`. Wouldn't this affect resizing of the image and then misplace the overlays?

Comment: i added a JSFiddle to illustrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/3NuDy/

Comment: @Sumit yes it would. But i assume your `background-position` is always the same. Regardless of that, have you thought about using imagemaps? It depends on what you are trying to achieve with the overlay div, but if it only should get an `click` handler then imagemaps would be a good way to go.

Comment: thank you, i'll look into both of your suggestions later today and provide feedback. Yes the overlays will get a simple onclick handler.

Comment: i made an answer. its not quite flawless, but i guess it will help you to understand what i mean!

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly, the following could work:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    var offsetdot = $('#dot').offset().left;
    console.log(width); // get reference width of window - in my case 692
    console.log(offsetdot); // get reference offset left of #dot - in my case 400

    var leftfactor = 400/692; // divide offset of width for the factor where the dot is
    newleft = leftfactor*width; // use factor to calculate new pos
    $('#dot').css('left', newleft); //insert new pos to left
});
```

It snaps on the first resize because your `width` value might be another than mine. But as you can see the red dot is always on the same width of the picture. All you need to do is do it with `top` as well.

Might help. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h2bgn/)

Edit: Its always on the same position, but you have to shrink the dot as well, because it does not change its size, that it appears slightly moving wrong. But it does not, as you can see if you are looking at the left border of the `#dot`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried yet, but I think you should position the overlay div's with percentual settings. If your background image's width stretches to the whole div's width, it is equivalent to 100%. So positioning your overlay divs with, let's say, `margin-left: 50%` would always put it to the same relative position of the container div.

Update: I build an example, have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/zpYQZ/8/

Comment: exactly but this is the opposite of what i need. The overlay divs have to be relative to the red spot in the image (or the iPhone, or any other spot in the image), not the container div.
The red spot in the last image is not the same percentual position as it is in the second image (relative to the div) - in this example: 80% (second image) vs 100% (third image).

Comment: to your update: you're just croppping the image to a smaller size with the same aspect ratio. `background-size: cover` causes the image to have different aspect ratios as seen in my provided images.

Comment: Wrong, your example pictures do not have different aspect ratios. Your example images above are cropped images rather than "covering" images that stretch to a div's shape.

Comment: If the image needs to be cropped and resized at the same time, it may be possible to tweak this jquery plugin to get the crop/resize factor out of it: https://code.google.com/p/resize-crop/. Then, you will be able to do almost anything you want with the image and yet, knowing what's going on with the spot.

Comment: You're right, Frederik, I'd go for JQuery, too. Nevertheless it's always kind of charming when you can do it with pure css ;)

Comment: as i said it's totally ok to use jQuery for my project. This is defenitely not a request for CSS only!